# How to replace framework's AP of Android

Tags: android, frameworks, screen, locked

I would like to write a standalone screen locked AP of Android to replace the default one(android\frameworks\policies\base\phone\com\android\internal\policy\impl\LockScreen.java
)

Does anyone know how to replace the default AP of framework?
   Is it possible to replace framework AP without modify any framework code?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know how to replace the
>   default AP of framework?

You have to [modify the firmware](http://source.android.com/).

> Is it possible to replace framework AP
>   without modify any framework code?

No. In particular, the lock screen is not designed to be replaceable at this time from the SDK. Perhaps in the future, but not today.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I saw there are some standalone screen lock APs just like "FlyScreen", "Lock 2.0" ..etc. If default screen lock AP can not be replaceed then user will see two screen lock APs be enabled at same time, one is default AP and another is FlyScreen or Lock 2.0 right? (I have some problems to install those demo APs on my emulator, so I don't verify this question yet.)

Comment: They are "lock screens" insofar as they exploit loopholes in the SDK and prevent the user from doing anything with the device. Those loopholes are being closed as they are found, AFAIK. AFAIK, those applications are *not* "lock screens" from an Android architecture standpoint, where "lock screen" is what the user sees when the phone returns out of sleep mode.

Comment: Dear Sir or Madam:

     Thanks you very much and Happey New Year!

     I found another slideunlocker AP from here:
     http://code.google.com/p/slideunlocker/

     When this slideunlocker ap executed on emulator, I pressed "end key" of emulator to let emulator enter suspend mode and then wake up emulator. 
I saw emulator display default unlock screen AP first. When I unlocked default AP then I saw this slideunlocker also ask user slide to unlock emulator. So, slideunlocker seems to meet what you said:the user sees when the phone returns out of sleep mode, right?

Comment: Even though I use slideunlocker this open source project, I still need to modify firmware to disable default screen locked ap, right?